# Add environment to a Azure Pipelines YAML when pushing a package to a feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pack and push a Net package to a DevOps feed.

Everything works fine but if I try to set an Environment I get the error:

```
Unexpected value 'environment'
```

I tried every version I could think of. What am I missing?

You can see the `environment: 'production'` in Pack and Push jobs.

And I also added that environment on Azure Devops project ...

**azure-pipelines.yaml**

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
  vm.image: 'ubuntu-latest'
  sdk.version: '8.x'
  build.configuration: 'release'
  devops.feed: '----'
  system.debug: true
  version: 8.0.4

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Setup
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: $(sdk.version)
        includePreviewVersions: true
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs: 
        command: build
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(build.configuration)'
- stage: Test
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Setup
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: $(sdk.version)
        includePreviewVersions: true
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Test
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: 'test/**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(build.configuration)'
- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Pack
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    environment: 'production'
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Setup
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: $(sdk.version)
        includePreviewVersions: true
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Pack
      inputs:
        command: pack
        projects: 'src/**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(build.configuration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        versioningScheme: byEnvVar
        versionEnvVar: version
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: Export
      inputs:
        artifact: $(build.configuration)
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - job: Push
    dependsOn: Pack
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    environment: 'production'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: Import
      inputs:
        artifact: $(build.configuration)
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Push'
      inputs:
        command: push
        packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg'
        publishVstsFeed: $(devops.feed)       
        versioningScheme: byEnvVar
        versionEnvVar: version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`environment` you may use in [Deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops). You may try updating your yaml to

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
 .....
- stage: Test
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Test
......
- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: Test
  jobs:
  - deployment: Pack
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    environment: 'production'
.....
  - deployment: Push
    dependsOn: Pack
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vm.image)
    environment: 'production'
.......
```

Or remove `environment: 'production'` from your definition.